# How to change the orientation of an svg text

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I am trying to orient my text Y-label to go from top to bottom - I have it working from bottom to top but changing the rotation is not doing it for me

Here is my Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/ghP0armaGK7NYhZfhzTs?p=preview

The code that is of interest is

```
 svg.append("text")
          .attr("class", "y label")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("y", -width/12 )
          .attr("x", -height/3) 
          .attr("dx","-5em")
          .attr("dy", "-.75em")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .text(yLabel);
```

With -90 the Y Label "Value" goes from bottom to top but what I want is "top" to "bottom".

(I tried -270 only to see the text get knocked out of the screen. I am clearly not understanding how rotate transform works)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to faff around calculating the offsets of rotated elements. You'll only end up with an ugly mash of numbers that will make no sense to anyone and will be a nightmare to maintain.

The SVG renderer can do all of these calculations for you. Just use a `<g>` element to transform the coordinate origin to the place you're interested in, then do the rotation. Everything parented to this element will then rotate around it, instead of orbiting some distant unrelated location.

Here's a quick hack to show you how it works. You might need to adjust some of the values, but I hope you get the picture.

```js
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(-"+width*0.1+","+height*0.45+")")
.append("text")
.attr("class", "y label")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.text(yLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

After rotation, you need to translate the text by the y-axis offset and the height offset (text is rotated around the specified x and y for the element, not the center of the displayed text as you were expecting).  For example, modifying your translate to this does the job (you'll want to use your variables appropriately, I just plugged in numbers that worked as an example):

```
.attr("transform", "translate(-75, 350) rotate(90)")
```

You can also modify your `x` and `y` so that it is the center of text element (using `dx` and `dy` to offset appropriately) so that the text rotates around the center point, which is probably the cleaner approach but I tend to just do a translate fix-up and be on my way.

Comment: Thanks for that. That works but I am not understanding why it works. How did you arrive at the numbers -75 and 350? I assume it is some kind of function of my width and height of the svg. What do you mean by "x" and "y" for the element; are you referring to the text element itself?

Comment: Yes, the x and y property of the text element. That is the origin point for the rotation. There is more information at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-transformation.html#rotate and more things you can do with text starting at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html#rotating-text. An alternative to the method I showed is to pass in a new origin point to your rotation.